# Extracting the last problem_id for every user

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns: `['user_id', 'problem_id', 'timestamp']`. So basically who solved what and when. Clearly there are users who solved many many problems.

I want to extract the last problem solved by every user. My first approach was to group by user_id and get the maximum: `df_s.groupby('user_id').max()[['problem_id']]`, but after looking at it more closely I realized that it will just return me the highest lexicographically ordered problem solved by the user.

I also clearly can iterate over groupby aggregation, sort the dataframe and take the first problem, but I hope for a quick one/few liners.

Comment: So `problem_id` is not an integer then? Otherwise, `df_s.groupby('user_id')['problem_id'].max()` is what you're after...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy it is a hex string. But even if it will be an integer, max will most probably just return me the highest integer from the list of problem_ids that user solved and not the latest

Comment: Ahhh okies - got ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `timestamp` sorts naturally - ie - latest values are last, then:

```
df_s.sort_values('timestamp').groupby('user_id').last()
```

Should give you what you want as `groupby` retains the order of its input for grouping...

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about last, first aggregations.